# Evaluating $\iiint_R \log\Big((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^\frac{3}{2}\Big)\, dx\ dy\ dz$ between balls in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am working on the following problem:

Evaluate:

$$\iiint_R \log\Big((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^\frac{3}{2}\Big)\, dx\ dy\ dz,$$

where $R = \big\{(x, y, z) : 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2^2 \big\}$ is the region between the unit ball and the ball of radius $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Firstly, I have sketched the region in the $xyz$-plane, but am finding it difficult to determine the limits of integration, especially for the innermost integral sign.

Secondly, I have noticed that the integrand is not straightforward.  However, it is similar to the definition of the region $R$ (especially because of the term $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$).

I am aware of the following methods, but am not sure which, if any, would be best for this problem:

- Changing the order of integration.
- Changing the variables and/or the coordinates.

I would appreciate hints regarding making progress with the problem.

Comment: You should use polar spherical coordinates here. So $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$

Comment: @NikitaEvseev: so far in my course, I have learnt about $3$-$d$ cylindrical coordinates and $3$-$d$ spherical coordinates.  However, the notion of polar spherical coordinates hasn't mentioned.  What exactly are these?

Comment: I mean $3-d$ spherical coordinates.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev: Ah, that is helpful.